# Idle Jenkins takes up approx 700 MB of RAM

Tags: linux, jenkins, outofmemoryerror

I just did a fresh install of jenkins master on a private virtual server having 1 GB of RAM. I have not yet installed anything else besides Jenkins on that server. I reduced the number of executors to 1. When I start the jenkins services it consumes approx. 700 MB of RAM just being idle:

[image]

What is up with all those child processes??

As a comparison here is after I stopped the Jenkins service:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look in Jenkin's startup script ( usually /etc/init.d/jenkins ) to find the config dir:

```
JENKINS_CONFIG=/etc/sysconfig/jenkins
```

Then look the provided file and look for:

```
JENKINS_HANDLER_IDLE="20"
```

Set that to what ever you want it to be, and you won't have so many children.

If that is set too high, you can run out of filehandles.

To fix that, first

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

That give you a rough idea of how many open files the system can really tolerate

you can go to /etc/security/limits.d and create a file 10-nofiles.conf

set something like this:

```
# Default for number of open files

*          soft    nofile     200000
*          hard    nofile     220000
root       soft    nofile     400000
root       hard    nofile     440000
```

Make sure never to exceed the file-max you catted out above..